# Как присвоить класс блоку по клику с записью в куки?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Структура новостей примерно такая.

```
<div id="1">
  .....
   <a href="">кнопка</a>
</div>

<div id="2">
  .....
   <a href="">кнопка</a>
</div>

<div id="3">
  .....
   <a href="">кнопка</a>
</div>
```

Как добавить к `div` класс `views` но только к тому в котором расположена кнопка и записать это в куки вот с этим плагином https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Вот что-то смастерил, но запоминается только последняя нажатая ссылка 
`   var cookieName = 'level';
    var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};

```
$("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("views");

$(".play").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr("id"), cookieOptions);
    $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("views");
});`
```

ссылки такие 
`<div class="shortplaypanel"><a id="Player{news-id}" href="">кнопка</a></div>`
 и так далее, меняется только `{news-id}`

Как сделать чтобы все ссылки с разными id запоминались, а не только последняя нажатая?

Comment: Или просто если есть куча ссылок на странице `<a id="1" href="">кнопка</a>` и `<a id="2" href="">кнопка</a>` по нажатию чтоб менялся стиль этой ссылки. Чтобы после перезагрузки страницы она оставалась для пользователя в таком же состоянии

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest("div").addClass("views");
   $.cookie('views', $(this).closest("div").attr("id"));
});
```

И не забывайте, что id должен с буквы начинаться.

Чтение куки после перезагрузки страницы и добавление класса:

```
var id = $.cookie('views');
$("#" + id).addClass("views");
```

Comment: Класс добавляется, но не запоминается div с кнопкой изменил на такой `<div id="box{news-id}">
   <a href="">кнопка</a>
</div>`

Comment: В куках должен быть  id слоя с нажатой кнопкой, проверьте еще раз

Comment: У меня `{news-id}` в каждом блоке разный

Comment: Перезагружаю страницу, этот класс пропадает

Comment: А ещё этот класс добавляется и к другим кнопкам, ко всем кнопкам на сайте

Comment: Чтобы после перезагрузки класс оставался, нужно его как-то проставлять)

Comment: А я думал это и есть запись в куки, чтоб блок с `id` таким-то был с классом `views` или без него.

Comment: Или просто если есть куча ссылок на странице `<a id="1" href="">кнопка</a>` и `<a id="2" href="">кнопка</a>` по нажатию чтоб менялся стиль этой ссылки. Чтобы после перезагрузки страницы она оставалась для пользователя в таком же состоянии

Comment: Посмотрите я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Чтобы после перезагрузки страницы у вас проставился класс на слой, нужно прочитать куки с именем views, там будет id. Ему присвоить класс.

Comment: Чет я не понял. Если имя будет views то id будет просто перезаписываться в этом имени. Как я представляю, что имя должно быть разное, у каждой ссылки своё, и у каждого имени запись в куках со своим id, а потом если есть в куках id то добавляется к ссылке с id класс views.